# Swith from Linux VM to Windows VM docker toolbox windows 8.1

Tags: windows, docker, kitematic

I have installed docker toolbox for windows 8.1, it has installed 3 things virtual box, Kitematic and docker terminal. When I run kitematic it is always configuring Linux VM. How to configure Windows? I couldn't find any option to swith from Linux to Windows.

I am getting this error:
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
909c0cde5070: Download complete
[ERROR]: Build docker image failed: image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.